# AdMob status is inactive but I'm receiving house ads

Tags: android, admob

I uploaded an application in the Android Market yesterday, I'm receiving house ads on my application and occasionally I also receive 3rd party ads (Checked on my phone). But my AdMob developer dashboard says my status for this Application is inactive. I have disabled test ads on the server side and also in my code. I have more than 400 users, but still nothing seems to be working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my publisher ID, I used another application's publisher ID and now after correcting it, everything works fine.